# What do you call a person who talks bad about someone but still shows interest in that person?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, meaning-in-context

For example: Sally Mae says she doesn’t like John because he’s ugly, but will go and act nice with him because others are watching.

What word would you use to describe Sally Mae?

Comment: Please do not answer in comments.

Comment: Funny how nobody ever shows up here asking for our help in saying something ***nice*** about somebody else. Instead it's always about saying horrible things about something we disapprove of, even though this has never required fancy words to sting the worst.

Answer (score 1):

A possible term is "self-monitoring". From [Is It Fake To Act Differently Around Different People?](https://www.succeedsocially.com/faketoactdifferent)

> A psychology term for this is *self-monitoring*. It's the degree to which someone pays attention to how they're coming across and adjusts their presentation and behavior based on the circumstances.